# How can I use the Inverse Function Theorem to prove this statement true or false?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb R)$ and  $H_f (2, 5)$ is positive-definite, then $(x, y) \mapsto (\partial_x f(x, y), \partial_y f(x, y))$ admits a inverse around $(2, 5)$. How can I use the Inverse Function Theorem to prove this?

Comment: I just saw that you already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463558/local-inverse-around-2-5). You should probably provide an attempt before asking something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a map $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 : (x,y) \mapsto (\partial_x f(x,y), \partial_y f(x,y))$. This map has Jacobian equal to the Hessian of $f$, which has a non-zero determinant at $(2,5)$.